# Spring XD Dynamic Module ClassLoader Issue

Tags: classloader, spring-xd

According to the documentation we can load jars dynamically at module creation time by exploiting the attribute **module.classloader** in the .properties file :

http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#module-class-loading

I spent two days trying to test this feature. It does not work. The option **module.classloader** seems to be simply ignored

I did not find any string named **module.classloader** in the XD code. But I found another one called **module.classpath** in this class:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-module/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/module/options/ModuleUtils.java

The code in the above class seems to match the documentation. But unfortunalletely it does not work too. My classes are not found and I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I have module option named **dir4jars** where I put the jars to load at creation time (when I issue job create --name xx --defintion ..). It's a directory, and I have tested the following possibilities, with both **module.classpath** and **module.classloader** :

```
module.classpath=${dir4jars}/*.jar
module.classloader=${dir4jars}/*.jar
.
.
job create --name jobName --definition "myJobModuleName --dir4jars=C:/ELS/Flash/libxd" --deploy

and

job create --name jobName --definition "myJobModuleName --dir4jars=file:C:/ELS/Flash/libxd" --deploy
```

I need the **dir4jars** to be absolute and outside XD home.
So my questions:

- What's the right option to use for this dynamic load? **module.classpath** or **module.classloader** ?
- How can I set an absolute directory as I mentioned above?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to be `module.classpath` and `module.classloader` looks like a mistake in the documentation. Does this work when you explicitly use `module.classpath=file:C:/ELS/Flash/libxd`?

As a side note: Please consider using [Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/) which is the successor of Spring XD.

Comment: This feature is really bad made in XD :-( when you read the code there no log, and worst the Container stop running when my issue occurs ! Regarding Spring Cloud Data Flow it's not yet in production, and we need to master other technologies to make it running... it's out of the context of my project....

Comment: Spring Cloud Data Flow is used in production and 1.0 GA was release in July 2016. I don't think you have to master other technologies to make Spring Cloud Data Flow running. This doc can help: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#migration-guide